# Ionic Android app plays video upside down

Tags: android, video, ionic-framework

I'm writing an Ionic App which allows user to upload video to server or get a list of url's from. Everything works ok, but after compile and run it on Android, when I get the list of the videos from server and i try to play one, it plays upside down. If i go fullscreen, everything is ok, but inline is upside down.

Here's my code

```
<div class="list card" ng-repeat="y in video.urls" >
    <div class="item item-avatar">
         <p>{{y.creationTime}}</p>
    </div>
     <div class="item item-body">
         <video   controls="controls" controls >
             <source  ng-src="{{y.src | to_trusted_url}}" type="video/mp4">
         </video>
         <p>
          {{y.description}}
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "upside down"? What happens when you turn the device?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice well, if i turn the device, the video remains turned and i can see it ok, but i need to see it also without turning the device. Also if i go full screen mode, the video plays ok, but when i leave full screen mode, it turns upside down again